# Add page title to custom theme on Magento

Tags: magento

How would you add a page title to custom theme out of content area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean a CMS page? I'm not sure what you're asking. If you're talking about the `<title></title>` tags in CMS pages, you set those in the Magento CMS manager, under the page you're trying to edit where it says "Page Title" - if that's not what you're looking for, please elaborate on your question.